# Change zoom level with setFocus for multiple regions in jVectorMap

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

I have data series with multiple region filter function.

I have setFocus enabled in my map to be able to center the map once filtered.

It seems to be that the scale is only working with single region selection.

Is it possible to zoom out by 2 levels the map once filtered?

Here is a sample dataset:

```
var codes = ['AU', 'AF', 'BD', 'IN'];
```

Here's my map settings:

```
var map = new jvm.Map({
  container: $('#jvectormap-wrapper'),
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  zoomOnScroll: false,
  series: {
    regions: [{
      values: codes,
      normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
    }]
  },
  regionStyle: {
    initial: {
      fill: '#eee'
    }
  },
});
```

Here's a sample dataset of the filtered values

```
var filteredCodes = ['AU', 'AF'];
```

Here's my settings for centering the map according to filtered values:

```
map.setFocus({
  regions: filteredCodes
});
map.setScale(5);
```

It seems that setScale isn't working and throws error:

```
jquery.jvectormap.min.js:1 Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected number, "scale(AU,AF...".
```

So, I tried another workaround by using the latLng to setFocus. It seems to be working, but I can't find a documentation on how to setFocus by latLng using an array of coordinates.

Here's a working setFocus by latLng:

```
map.setFocus({
  scale: 5,
  lat: lat,
  lng: lng,
});
```